# Slowdown in docker-compose version 2 vs version 1

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file, with the following general content:

```
mongo:
    image: mongoimage    
    expose:
        - "27017"
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"

mysql:
    image: mysqlimage
    expose:
        - "3306"
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"

data:
    image: dataimage

memcached:
    image: memcached

webserver:
    image: webserverimage
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "5000:5000"
        - "12500:12500"
    expose:
        - "5000"
        - "12500"
    links:
        - mongo
        - mysql
        - memcached
    hostname: localtesting.dev
    volumes_from:
        - data
    volumes:
        - localvolume1:/mountedvolume1
        - localvolume2:/mountedvolume2
        - localvolume3:/mountedvolume3
        - localvolume4:/mountedvolume4
        - localvolume5:/mountedvolume5

testing:
    image: testingimage
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    links:
        - mongo
        - mysql
        - webserver:localtesting.dev
    volumes_from:
        - webserver
```

When I run this through our local testsuite, which consists of a lot of http requests from testing to webserver, it takes about 1 hour.

I modified it to docker version 2:

```
version: '2'
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongoimage    
        expose:
            - "27017"
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"

    mysql:
        image: mysqlimage
        expose:
            - "3306"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

    data:
        image: dataimage

    memcached:
        image: memcached

    webserver:
        image: webserverimage
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "5000:5000"
            - "12500:12500"
        expose:
            - "5000"
            - "12500"
        links:
            - mongo
            - mysql
            - memcached
        hostname: localtesting.dev
        volumes_from:
            - data
        volumes:
            - localvolume1:/mountedvolume1
            - localvolume2:/mountedvolume2
            - localvolume3:/mountedvolume3
            - localvolume4:/mountedvolume4
            - localvolume5:/mountedvolume5

    testing:
        image: testingimage
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - mongo
            - mysql
            - webserver:localtesting.dev
        volumes_from:
            - webserver
```

When I run it now through the local testsuite, it suddenly takes about 6 hours, with all http requests taking a lot longer. What network changes should I make to remove the extra latency, and what is the actual cause behind it?